# Creating a python function to output a periodic function

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python function that makes the output a periodic function. But, I do not know how to code a variable, say X, to work as the output. I know to use Sympy for something with an output of x**2, but for some reason I cannot use the variable the same way. When I try to use sympy to get some output function that would be, for a random example, cos(4x), the error explanation I get from python is "'Symbol' object has no attribute 'cos'". How can I write a function that could give me the output cos(4x) in python where the output is cos(4x) the function, not cos(4x) evaluated at some predetermined x)?

Comment: `def my_cos(x):\n return math.cos(4 * x)`

Comment: `math.cos(4*x)` ?

Comment: but first you should `import math`  ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  However, I expect that the previous comments should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: the thing is I want the output to be cos(4x) where x is just a variable, not a number I am inputting. Sorry I should have been more clear. I want my output to be a function.

Comment: Ok, let's put it a different way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically I am writing a large function that sums cos(kx)+sin(kx) at k values. so For example k a list of numbers [1,2,3] so what I want my function to output is cos(x)+sin(x)+cos(2x)+sin(2x)+cos(3x)+sin(3x). The output is a cosine function at an undetermined x.

Comment: the thing is I don't want some x=4 evaluation, I just want the general function as my output. I want my python run of the shell to give me "cos(x)+sin(x)+cos(2x)+sin(2x)+cos(3x)+sin(3x)" not evaluated at any x. I just want the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

functions are objects.  You can define a function inside a function and then return that newly defined function.  These are referred to as [closures](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures)

```
import sympy

def expansion(coef1, coef2):
    def exp(x):
        return sympy.cos(coef1*x) + sympy.cos(coef2*x)
    return exp

c1 = 1
c2 = 2

my_exp = expansion(c1, c2)

x = sympy.symbols("x")
print(my_exp(x))
```

prints:

```
cos(x) + cos(2*x)
```

Comment: but how could you make it so print(math.cos(c1*x)+math.cos(c2*x)) gives you cos(x)+cos(2x), where x is not defined as pi/4, or as anything at all?

Comment: the returned closure makes no assumptions about the value of x, so you can evaluate it for whatever value of x you want.  Are you ever looking to evaluate the expression, or you purely want the symbolic representation for latex or something?

Comment: I am never looking to evaluate the expression, I just want to create the expression. And for some reason that is very complicated to do in python.

Comment: what is the expression for ultimately, I think that point is unclear, but important to determining what we're trying to achieve here

Comment: the expression is not for anything, which I know is odd. Sorry this is unclear. Basically I am doing a long assignment which I don't want to post as I want to do the assignment on my own/ make whatever errors on my own/ etc. But the ultimate answer is an unevaluated mathematical function. I had to do a lot of coding to find k values and what not, but my ultimate answer needs to be something like P(x)= cos(4x)+cos(5x). We never need to input x values, just need to get the right function.

Comment: well, the principle of closures is exactly the same, but you just do it with sympy rather than math, answer has been updated, is this what you're looking for

Comment: Yes this is it exactly. Thank you! Sorry for all the confusion

Comment: if that is correct, an accepted answer is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment :

> Basically I am writing a large function that sums cos(kx)+sin(kx) at k values. so For example k a list of numbers [1,2,3] so what I want my function to output is cos(x)+sin(x)+cos(2x)+sin(2x)+cos(3x)+sin(3x). The output is a cosine function at an undetermined x.

Try this way :

```
import math
def func(x, arr):
    res = 0
    for k in arr:
        res += (math.cos(k*x) + math.sin(k*x))
    return res
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [1,2,3]
    x = 4
    print(func(x, arr))
```

Comment: this would work for say x=4, but I need it to output cos(4x) where x is an undetermined variable. I want the output to be a general function.

Comment: You can define a function inside the function and then return that defined function by name

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: see my example answer below